# What is the default value of Register in C

Tags: c

In C,I've heard that the Register specifier's default value is garbage.Some sources say there is no register's default value,so errors may occur if you don't initialize the variable with register specifier.I tried this example.When I executed the code,The program showed me register's default value as 1.I don't know which source I should believe and I don't know the "garbage" term.Could you explain it for me?
Here is the code I executed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
register int a;
printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: `1` (or even `0`) if uninitialized is garbage.

Comment: When I run this code I get: `-13200`.  That doesn't mean the default value is that.

Comment: `register` is a thing of the past. Your question applies to ANY variable unless declared globally or with `static` storage duration. Variables have an *indeterminate* value until initialized.

Answer (score 2):

`register` is nothing but a hint to the compiler, and it's completely ignored nowadays. The regular POD initialization rules apply, and in this case your variable will not be initialized with anything (ie its contents is what is colloquially known as garbage).

Comment: Can you define POD (i.e. not use an acronym)?

Comment: Sure, [here you go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure). It's a data structure with no initializer (no constructor in C++).

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.  Is it, in C, there's no constructor to initialize objects?

Comment: Exactly. In fact there's exactly one case where data is zeroed in C, when you define it as a static with pre-defined data, and it gets mapped over the text section of the generated executable. And in C++ any type that doesn't have a constructor is called POD and follows C rules for initializing (plus a whole slew of fun `new T` vs `new T()` rules).

Comment: The "POD" distinction is unnecessary in C since there's no constructor-like initialization available in C language.

Comment: `register` is not completely ignored; if an object is defined with `register`, then its address may not be taken.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: When using gcc with optimization level 0, the `register` storage class can have a huge impact on code efficiency, sometimes allowing a compiler to generate code that's almost as good as (and sometimes even more efficient than) what the compiler would generate at a higher optimization setting.

Answer (score 2):

The register keyword is ignored by the compilers and they decide where to place the object. It will be same not initialized as automatic variable.

Some compiler have extension allowing static assignment of the register to the variable. For example gcc.

```
register int p1 asm ("r7");
```

of defined in the global scope the register `r7` will taken out of the register pool and used as variable `p1`. The functions from the same compilation unit will not use this register. Other functions may destroy it).

When defined in local scope it is very likely compiler to optimize it usage.

Still there will not be the address of this variable available.

Comment: When using `-O0`, gcc will place values which aren't qualified `register` in memory, but will often store those which are thus qualified in registers.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know the "garbage" term.

“Garbage” is sloppy language. For the most part, what people mean by it is “We are not controlling what is there.” That does not mean it is random (nobody makes an effort to put random data there) or that it is garbage (it is not necessarily data with no value or meaning). (Consider that an attacker looking for defects in a program might find uninitialized data, and that data might actually contain clues to bank account numbers, passwords, cryptographic keys or other data—it is dangerous to assume uninitialized data is just garbage.)

> In C,I've heard that the Register specifier's default value is garbage.

With a very simple compiler, or some compilers with optimization turned off, a program may be translated literally so that an `int x` is assigned some memory space, and using the value of `x` loads the data from that memory, and that a `register int y` is assigned some register, and using the value of `y` uses the data in that register. However, in modern compilers using optimization, this is not what happens in general.

Instead, the C source code represents a program that runs in an abstract computer. In the abstract model, that program does load the data from the memory assigned to `x`, for example. However, the compiler does not generate instructions to implement that program. The compiler analyzes the program to figure out how to get the same results as the program but faster.

For this purpose, the only results that matter for being the “same results” are those that are defined by the C standard to be observable. Those results are:

- The output of the program, including all data written into files.
- The input and output interactions (so prompts written to standard output must appear before input is taken, if the abstract program is written that way).
- Accesses to `volatile` objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

Aside from these, the compiler can reorganize the program in any way it wants. When the value of `x` is used in an expression, the compiler does not have to load it from memory if it already has a copy in a register from some previous work. Or, if `6*x` is needed, and the compiler does not have that or `x` handy, but it does have a copy of `3*x`, then the compiler can just take `3*x` and double it instead of loading `x` from memory to calculate `6*x`. And much more complicated optimizations are possible too.

What happens if you never initialize `x`, whether it is in memory or in a register? The C standard does not say what happens (with some caveats). That means the program in the abstract computer is not defined to do anything particular. Then the optimizer in the compiler can derive anything it wants from this. If `x` is used in an expression, the optimizer does not have to load it from memory at all, nor, if `x` is nominally assigned to a register, does the compiler have to use that register for `x`. This is because, if `x` was never initialized, then the rules of the C standard does not say it has any particular value. So it does not matter if the memory assigned to `x` has the contents 1234 but the compiler uses some unrelated register that contains 5678 because **the rules of the C standard say that the memory could have had 5678 in it**. As far as the compiler is concerned, using uncontrolled data from a register is the same as using uncontrolled data from memory, so there is no reason to bother actually loading data from memory; it would be a waste of time.

That is an overview. There are specific rules in the C standard about:

- when a value may be some unspecified value but cannot trap (generate an exception and terminate your program, or do other things),
- when a value not only may be some unspecified value but can be a different value each time you use it,
- when using an uninitialized value can cause a trap.

Answer (score 0):

C does not implicitly initialize objects with `auto` storage duration (i.e., local or block-scope variables), so they will contain whatever was last written to that particular chunk of memory.  That value could be `1`, or `0`, or `-1234`, or quite literally anything else.

You shouldn't be *surprised* to see a `1` in an uninitialized `auto` variable, because you shouldn't be surprised to see *any* value.

The term "garbage" is simply shorthand for "you can't *rely* on it being any specific value".  It might be better to use the term "indeterminate" instead.