# Can a variable have no value at all?

Tags: c, variables

When we declare a variable it is assigned a memory location. The location may already have a value, and if we don't initialize the variable, it will point to that already present value, which is called garbage value.

So even if we ourselves don't set a value to variable it will still point to a value.

But is this always true? What if there is no value at the memory location and we don't initialize the variable? What type error will I get when I try to do something, for example arithmetic, with the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "no value at the memory location"? AFAIK, there's always some "value", always some kind of bits in RAM.

Comment: Can you give an example of a bit pattern that is not a garbage value? ;)

Comment: "_What type error will I get when I try to do something, for example arithmetic, with the variable?_" Modern compilers will detect this issue and emit a warning along the lines of "variable x uninitialised before use"... "Global (and static) variables" will always be initialised.

Comment: There is not such thing as "no value at the memory location". Any memory cell available to the program contains some combination of bits.

Comment: Don't understand what you want and why. Maybe there is need of tag like `philosophy` in addition to `C`. If you need to reserve memory, define variable like `reserved1` and do not use it.

Comment: Sane memory always has a value made of bits 0/1. So you can always associate a numerical value to one or more mem cells. What you mean is maybe the "significance" of that value. With integers, all possible bits combinations equal to a value (by convention). But, you could indeed have impossible combinations of bytes that compose  C double (case of IEEE754) for instance, NaN, yet the memory is not "empty".

Comment: @i486 this question arose while studying a C language book, and not while writing a program, so I don't have any practical reason to ask this question, I just found this problem interesting and didn't know the answer and hence asked it here.

Comment: https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2220.htm

Comment: Stack Overflow's scope explicitly is limited to questions about the _practice_ of software development. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard does not specify how programs behave in physical computers. It specifies the behavior of programs in an abstract model. In the abstract model, an uninitialized object does not have a fixed value.

In this model, an uninitialized object is said to have an *indeterminate value*. (C 2018 6.7.9 10: “If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate…”) An indeterminate value is “either an unspecified value or a trap representation” (3.19.2). An *unspecified value* is, per 3.19.3:

> valid value of the relevant type where this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

In other words, the “value” of an uninitialized object is unspecified in **each instance** in which it is used. If you print it three times in a row, the result of printing may be “3”, “4”, and “-11729301”.

In the memory hardware you will find in an ordinary general-purpose computer, any memory location will, after the operating system is started and has provided memory to a user process, hold some particular value. But the behavior of C programs is not specified to tie the behavior of an uninitialized object to any particular memory location. So while any memory location may have some fixed value, the object in the abstract model of the C standard may not.

I discuss this further in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66840190/298225), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326611/how-garbage-values-are-assigned-to-variables-in-c/65307907#65307907), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902234/what-is-the-default-value-of-register-in-c/62903376#62903376), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69863881/default-values-for-long-datatype-in-c-programming/69863925#69863925).

There is an additional rule in 6.3.2.1 2 that says:

> … If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

In this case, it is the entire behavior of the program that is undefined, not just the value of the object.

Answer (score 2):

> *Can a variable have no value at all?*

When a variable with automatic storage duration is declared and takes a memory address, that memory address will have something in it.

---

> *So even if we ourselves don't set a value to variable it will still point to a value.*
> *But is this always true?*

Always is, perhaps, too definitive, but I would say yes, pretty much, given the above scenario.

---

> *What if there is no value at the memory location and we don't initialize the variable? What type error will I get when I try to do something, for example arithmetic, with the variable?*

Reading or modifying the value in the object represented by that variable, before initialization, will amount to undefined behavior, as the defined in the C international standard:

#### §3.4.3 (C11 N1570)

> 1. *undefined behavior
>    behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.*
> 2. *NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).*
> 3. *EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.*

As the definition states there is no requirements for the behavior of such program, so anything can happen, it is true that modern compilers, with the right flags, will warn, or even issue an error, you if you try to do it.

Comment: Using the value of an uninitialized object does not always caused undefined behavior. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, using the value of an uninitialized object of automatic storage duration whose address is not taken causes undefined behavior. Otherwise, the object has an indeterminate value but the behavior is not otherwise undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil l don't follow, your comment states: "using the value of an uninitialized object of automatic storage duration whose address is not taken causes undefined behavior", otherwise... the value is not used, in this case there's no UB. Still, I'll change my answer to avoid possible erroneous statements.

Comment: By “using the value,” I mean accessing an object to read its value. Specifically, this is lvalue conversion as specified in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2. This answer states “… accessing its value will generally amount to undefined behavior”. In the C standard, it is not values that are accessed but objects, and “access” is defined (3.1) to mean “to read or modify the value of an object.” So, `x = 3;` access `x` to set its value to 3, and that access does not cause undefined behavior even if `x` is uninitialized…

Comment: … In the statement `x;`, the lvalue `x` is normally converted to the value stored in `x`, per 6.3.2.1 2 mentioned above. If `x` is not initialized, it has an unspecified value. This is not always undefined behavior. Only if `x` has automatic storage duration and its address is not taken (even after the use of `x` in question) is the behavior undefined. For example, in `unsigned char x; printf("%hhu\n", x); scanf("%hhu", &x);`, the behavior is defined: The `printf` must execute, and it must print some value for `x`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see, you're right, bad description on my part. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The closest any RAM cell can get to "no value" at all is never having been written to at all. That is unlikely in any computer which gets to the point of executing any program you created, but not impossible, so let's assume that it is the case.

Then going a little into detail (still very much simplifying) the most relevant RAM constructs are dynamic memory and static memory (not to be confused with static linking and dynamic memory allocation).

Dynamic memory is more or less a capacity, which needs regular refreshing by having the stored value written again, which is done by memory management units (MMUs) automatically. These MMUs do their job very much in the background. Practically always this defeats the assumption that no value has ever been written. But let's assume a MMU which somehow only works on cells that never have had a value intentionally written (almost guaranteed never to be created, because it is complex, expensive and without any "saving" value).

Static RAM is a little circuit with the attribute that they have two self-stabilising states, usually high voltage or low voltage. Any in between value is fast driven to one of the defined values. But let's not consider that "intentional writing". In essence that makes them hard to predict. Some static RAM types have a tendency to 1 or 0, but compilers never assume that and they should not be relied upon. So while "random" is the wrong expression (especially if your goal were actual randomness), it is a suitable model.

Both kinds of RAM will however be read intentionally at one point, probably by your program, because that is why you are asking.

The physical act of reading involves, at the latest, a decision between 0 and 1 for each cell. The purpose of reading is to get a clear 1 or 0. The result might be "random" but it is a clear 1 or 0.
The total of several read cells, to make e.g. a byte, will be somewhat unpredictable, but it will be a set of 0s and 1s. All possible outcomes are within the datatypes range definition. Or a special value (in case of e.g. floats or some implementations of integers) which is not interpreted as a value, but it is not a specified "no value" which could be used.

Even looking at trinary logic, in contrast to binary, i.e. memory cells which can have three states (I doubt that is used in any existing computer of notable memory size...) the third state would surely not be used to signify "cannot be used". Doing trinary logic with three defined values would be much more efficient than any imaginable other use of a that unique ability.

In short, with a few very risky assumptions, a memory location for a variable can physically be in something of a special "never written" state; but at the point of reading it out, the result is not discernable from a value of the datatype which is mapped (avoiding the word "written" here) there (even including the special values).

If you want to keep track of memory locations or variables which have never been written to, you need to do that with defined "unwritten/written" values, probably boolean in OTHER variables referring to them.
In order to have them reliable in turn, you still need to initialise them cleanly.

Mapping to your questions (I do accept them as phrasing a single focused question):

- Can a variable have no value at all?
  Yes, for the internals of a memory cell.
  No, for a "variable" as in "a value read from a cell".
- But is this always true?
  Yes, for the best of my knowledge, in any easily bought and used computer.
- What if there is no value at the memory location and we don't initialize the variable?
  You still read a value (as opposed to physically having a state of the cell without reading...) indistinguishable from values read from an initialised cell.
- What type error will I get when I try to do something, for example arithmetic, with the variable?
  No clear error at runtime. Only the usual strange and hard to debug behaviour of programs with undefined behaviour - or no error at all, the worst outcome in my opinion.
  If you are lucky you get warnings or errors before execution; from compilers or static code analysis tools - or none at all (again, worst).

Comment: @Haris Thanks for the edit. Wow, I thought I was thorough with double-reading....

Answer (score 1):

> When we declare a variable it is assigned a memory location. The
> location may already have a value, and if we don't initialize the
> variable, it will point to that already present value, which is called
> garbage value.

If it has a memory location or not depends on the compiler. It may keep it in the register only or optimize it out completely. Only if you **use** the reference to it (or declare it as `volatile`) it will have the memory location.

- Variables having **static storage duration** will be zeroed if not
  explicitly initialized and their value will be well defined.
- Variables having **automatic storage duration** or **dynamic storage duration** will have unspecified value. But it will be something - but you as a programmer can't predict what.

> What type error will I get when I try to do something, for example
> arithmetic, with the variable?

You will not get any errors. If you use not **static storage duration** object without prior initialization or value assignment, your program will invoke undefined behaviour (UB) and its behaviour will be *undefined*.

```
int x;    // static storage duration - zeroed
static int x1;   // static storage duration - zeroed

void foo(void)
{
    int y;   //automatic storage duration - undefined
    static int z; // static storage duration - zeroed  
    int *p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1)); // p1 - automatic storage duration - initialized. Referenced object value undefined
    int *p2 = calloc(sizeof(*p2), 1); // p1 - automatic storage duration - initialized. Referenced object zeroed
 
    /* .... */
```